# Bundler http auth support

Tags: ruby, rubygems, http-authentication, bundler

does anyone know if Bundler supports http auth?  I'm *pretty* sure rubygems does (I think i read that somewhere) but I don't see anywhere in the docs where I might specify a username/pwd for a particular repo

I'm trying to run my own private gem server so as not to expose sensitive code

Comment: Bundler uses rubygems, so it should work the same way. Have you run into problems with it?

Comment: haven't tried yet, but I can't see any docs that give the syntax for specifying username/pwd in bundler.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/300 you can set the proxy settings the same as in rubygems.

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://[username]:[password]@[proxyserver]:[port]
```

http://dan-webb.co.uk/wordpress/?p=11

OR

```
# cat $HOME/.gemrc
gem: --source http://[username]:[password]@[proxyserver]:[port]/[DIRECTORY]
```

http://www.sun.com/bigadmin/content/submitted/ruby_http.jsp

Answer (score 0):

Bundler version 1.6 added HTTP auth in bundle config.